# How to disable select and copy in ckeditor

Tags: php, select, copy, ckeditor

Hi I am trying to implement selection and Copy feature in my application. I have been able to disable select and copy on entire website. But in ckeditor I am still able to select and copy. I am using PHP and mysql. Searched entire web but was unable to find solution.

Help!

Comment: with some help from chandu 
$( document ).ready(function() {
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
    removeButtons : 'Cut,Copy'

});
});
 I added this code in-page(index.php) after textarea. Now copy and cut buttons vanished. how do I disable ctrl+x and ctrl+v

Answer (score 0):

open the file CKEditor\CKEditor.js, remove copy from this list:

```
i.toolbar_Full=[['Source','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print','SpellChecker','Scayt'],['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],['Form','Checkbox','Radio','TextField','Textarea','Select','Button','ImageButton','HiddenField'],'/',['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','CreateDiv'],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],['BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],['Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe'],'/',['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor','BGColor'],['Maximize','ShowBlocks','-','About']];
```

or try to add this in your config file,

```
config.removeButtons = 'Copy';
```

Comment: I am not able to find "toolbar_Full" in the entire ckeditor.

Comment: I am not sure if i going wrong some where. config.removeButtons not affect anything. Should I include the config file somwhere.

Comment: Thanx now I implemented in-page config which is able to remove cut and copy buttons,  
$( document ).ready(function() {
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
    removeButtons : 'Cut,Copy'

});
});
  but still I am able to select and Ctrl+x and Ctrl+v. How do I disable them.